# Can’t create new file in Word 13

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, templates

When I select file new, there is no cursor or end of document marker. No menu options work. I can open an existing document and it works fine. Just can’t create a new one. Anyone seen this before? Maybe a damaged normal template? Thanks for any insight. Haven’t found any helpful topics.

Comment: Turn the existing new document template into a backup file by appending a .bak extension to the end of it. Then maybe Word will create a new default template automatically. If you have the installation disk, run one of the repair options options from the installation disk to repair Word.

Comment: Thank you, Karel.  I’ll try both!

Comment: I also voted to reopen this question and I am posting this link to the review reopen queue for other reviewers to review it: https://superuser.com/review/reopen/958377